# How to convert text-based table to image from terminal in the same structure?

Tags: centos, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to convert text-based table to the image, but the structure is broken after convertation.

I have file with the next structure:

[image]

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
|  Adelaide | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
|  Brisbane | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
|   Darwin  | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
|   Hobart  | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
|   Sydney  | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
|   Perth   | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+%
```

after a conversation with ImageMagick and command below:

```
convert label:"$(cat test.txt)" result1.png
```

I have next image:

[image]

As you can see, the structure of the columns is broken.
Do you have an idea of how can such an issue be solved?

Regards,
Ihor

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the TypeFace to something monospace to match the terminal.

```
convert -font "Liberation-Mono" label:@test.txt result1.png
```

[image: result]

You can identify which fonts on the system by running

```
identify -list font | grep Mono
```